# Нужна ли в данном предложении запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Бренды, разработанные с участием этой компании — лидеры своих категорий.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Бренды, разработанные с участием этой компании, — лидеры своих категорий.**

Каждый из этих знаков препинания — и тире, и запятая — ставится на собственном основании:

1. Тире ставится, т. к. подлежащее (бренды) и сказуемое (лидеры) выражены существительными в именительном падеже.
   [Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/706-17_tire_mezhdu_podlezhaschim_i_skazuemym.html)
2. Перед тире ставится запятая, которая закрывает причастный оборот.
   [Запятая и тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176)

Comment: Дополнение. Запятая и тире могут и должны стоять рядом, если каждый знак поставлен по своей причине.

Comment: Вы считаете, что надо дополнить ответ? Просто эта информация есть во второй ссылке — я не стала" загружать".

Comment: Не все читают по ссылке, так что самое важное желательно писать в ответе.

Comment: Я дополнила ответ. Думаю, теперь все понятно.